# How to call etcdctl txn from python?

Tags: python, sh, etcd, etcdctl

I need to perform an ETCD transaction to check if `key_a` is of given revision, and if yes, then to delete the key, and put in a new `key_b` with value of `value_b`. I want to do that from python, and I am really struggling with the way `etcdctl txn` command works, to be specific, with the syntax of its input. Online examples on how to use `etcdctl txn` are very scarce. The solution I came up with, is to create the txn input, and pass it via pipe to the etcdctl txn:

```
        cmd = "'mod(\"/key_a\") = \"1\"\n\ndel /key_a\nput /key_b \"value_b\"\n\n\n' | etcdctl txn")
        ret = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

However, I receive an error I do not fully understand:

```
/bin/sh: 7: mod("/key_a") = "1"

del /key_a
put /key_b "value_b"


: not found
Error: EOF
3
```

**Where did I messed up? How can I create a one-liner to call `etcdctl txn`?**